# Using a continous assignment in a Verilog procedure?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

Is it possible and/or useful to ever use a continuous assignment in a Verilog procedure?  For example, would there ever be any reason to put an `assign` inside of an `always` block?

For example this code:

```
always @(*) 
begin 
  assign data_in = Data;
end
```

Furthermore would it be possible to generate sequential logic with this approach?

```
always @(posedge clk) 
begin 
  assign data_in = Data;
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called *procedural continuous assignment*. It is the use of an `assign` or `force` (and their corresponding counterparts `deassign` and `release`) within procedural block. A new continuous assignment process is created when the line is reached in the procedural block. `assign` can be applied to register types such as `reg`, `integer`, and `real`. `force` can be applied to registers and nets (i.e. `wire`s). It has been part of the LRM since 1364-1995.

- IEEE Std 1364-1995 § 9.3
- IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 9.3
- IEEE Std 1364-2005 § 9.3
- IEEE Std 1800-2005 § 25.3
- IEEE Std 1800-2009 § 10.6
- [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 10.6

Procedural continuous assignments are synthesizable, by most tools. However it is recommend to limit the use to behavior modeling of an analog block, test bench files, or fixing RTL<->gate functional mismatches.

- `always @* assign data_in = Data;`
   is functional the same as
   `always @* data_in = Data;`
- `always @(posedge clk) assign data_in = Data;`
   is functional the same as:

  ```
  always @(posedge clk)
    enable = 1;
  always @*
    if (enable==1) data_in = Data;
  ```

A valid use of procedural continuous assignment would be should be applited to the following:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n, negedge set_n) begin
   if (!rst_n)      q <= 1'b0;
   else if (!set_n) q <= 1'b1;
   else             q <= d;
end
```

It will synthesize to a flop with an asynchronous set and reset with priority to reset. In simulation however the model is inaccurate if `rst_n` and `set_n` are both low then `rst_n` goes high. `q` should go to 1 the the asynchronous set is still enabled, but nothing to trigger in in the sensitivity list. This is a well documented issue with Verilog. It is the one case procedural continuous assignment are allowed in RTL when used with the translate off keyword your synthesizer. The `release`/`deassign` allows the the register/wire to be assigned in the usual manner.

```
// translate_off
always @(rst_n or set_n)
  if (rst_n && !set_n) force q = 1'b1;
  else                 release q;
// translate_on
```

OR (currently valid but discouraged)

```
// translate_off
always @(rst_n or set_n)
  if (rst_n && !set_n) assign q = 1'b1;
  else                 deassign q;
// translate_on
```

Using `assign`/`deassign` in this manner is being considered to be depreciated in future IEEE 1800 release. IEEE Std 1800-2005 § 25.3, IEEE Std 1800-2009 § C.4.2 and [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § C.4.2 recognizes `assign` used this way causes confusion and is the source of errors. Use `force`/`release` if procedural continuous assignment as needed.

In generate using procedural continuous assignment (with `force`/`release`) should only be used if absolutely necessary. Alternative approaches are more reliable.

### Misuse of procedural continuous assignment and solutions:

- Combinational logic on `reg`:

  ```
  always @(sel)
    if (sel) assign reg1 = func1(x,y,z);
    else     assign reg1 = func2(a,b,c);
  ```

  - Solution:

    ```
    always @* // <- IEEE Std 1364-2001 construct
      if (sel) reg1 = func1(x,y,z);
      else     reg1 = func2(a,b,c);
    ```
- Combinational logic on `wire`:

  ```
  always @(sel)
    if (sel) force wire1 = func1(x,y,z);
    else     force wire1 = func2(a,b,c);
  ```

  - Solution:

    ```
    assign wire1 = sel ? func1(x,y,z) : func2(a,b,c);
    ```
- Sequential logic:

  ```
  always @(posedge clk)
    if (sel) assign reg2 = func1(x,y,z);
    else     assign reg2 = func2(a,b,c);
  ```

  - Solution (*assuming* original functionality is **wrong**):

    ```
    always @(posedge clk)
      if (sel) reg2 <= func1(x,y,z); // Non-blocking assignment !!!
      else     reg2 <= func2(a,b,c);
    ```
  - Solution (*assuming* original functionality is **correct**):

    ```
    reg flop_sel;
    always @(posedge clk)
      flop_sel <= sel; // Non-blocking assignment !!!
    always @*
      if (flop_sel) reg2 = func1(x,y,z); // Blocking assignment !!!
      else          reg2 = func2(a,b,c);
    ```

Comment: There is nothing unsynthesizable about a procedural continuous  assignment. `always @sel if (sel) assign out = in1 else assign out = in2;`  is perfectly synthesizable as a mux. The real problem was that that Verilog chose to use the same syntax/keyword for two features that are too similar. That was the cause of much confusion.

Comment: +1. I learned something. Looks like most tools support it; not [altera](http://quartushelp.altera.com/12.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_veri_procedural_assignment.htm) and yosys as examples. Still not recommended. It causes to much confusion.

Comment: @Greg What is the differnce between the solutions to the "Sequential logic" example? Do they behave differently?

Comment: The "assume original is wrong" calculates the combinational logic before setting the flop, lets call this Comb2Flop. The "assume original is correct" assigns the flop and uses it as a mux selector for combinational logic, lets call this Flop2Comb. The difference being `reg2` in Flop2Comb is asynchronous so a change `a/b/c/x/y/z` unrelated to the clock could change `reg2`'s value. `reg2` is only updated on a `posedge clk` for Flop2Comb. _Note: procedural continuous assignment in real designs are not common so I'm assuming any use of it is a newbie mistake._