# Verilog code - compiles fine, but simulation does not run

Tags: verilog, montgomery-multiplication

I have had some fairly good experiences with structural modelling in Verilog, but I barely have any with other modelling methods. So, kindly help me out.
The code compiles fine, but when simulating it just hangs. Nothing happens.
If it is important, the code is a Montgomery Modular Multiplier. It is a bit above my academic level, but I have managed to understand the algorithm and write the code. Why won't the simulation run? Thanks a lot in advance!

```verilog
module MMM42(A1,A2,B1,B2,N,S1,S2,clk);

   input clk;
   input [3:0]A1,A2,B1,B2,N;
   output [6:0]S1,S2;
   reg [3:0]a1,a2,b1,b2,n,bd1,bd2,d1,d2,w,y;
   reg [6:0]s1,s2,s11,s21,s12,s22;
   reg q,A,Ai1,Ai2,qi1,qi2,mbrfa_ctemp,bypass;
   reg temp1,temp2;
   integer i=0;

   initial
      begin
         assign q=1'h0;
         assign A=1'h0;
         assign s1=7'h0;
         assign s2=7'h0;
         assign bd1=(B1<<1)^(B2<<1);
         assign bd2=(B1<<1)&(B2<<1);
         assign d1=bd1^bd2^n;
         assign d2=bd1&bd2&n;
         assign mbrfa_ctemp=1'h0;
         assign bypass=1'h0;
         assign qi1=1'h0;
         assign qi2=1'h0;
         assign s11=7'h0;
         assign s21=7'h0;
         assign s12=7'h0;
         assign s22=7'h0;
         assign w=4'h0;
         assign y=4'h0;
         assign Ai1=1'h0;
         assign Ai2=1'h0;
      end

   always 
      begin 
         assign a1=A1;
         assign b1=B1;
         assign a2=A2;
         assign b2=B2;
         assign n=N;
      end

   always @(posedge clk)
      begin
         while(i<6)
            begin

               //mbrfa
               assign temp1=(a1[i]&a2[i]);//carry_i+1
               assign temp2=(a1[i+1]&a2[i+1]);//carry_i+2
               assign mbrfa_ctemp=bypass?temp1:temp2;//mux
               assign Ai1=a1[i]^a2[i]^mbrfa_ctemp;//A_i+1
               assign Ai2=a1[i+1]^a2[i+1]^temp1;//A_i+2

               //look-ahead unit
               assign qi1=s11[1];//q_i+1
               assign qi2=s21[1]^s11[2];q_i+2
               assign bypass=~(qi1|Ai1);
               assign q=bypass?qi2:qi1;//q_bar
               assign A=bypass?Ai2:Ai1;//A_bar

               //iteration variable
               i=bypass?i+2:i+1;

               //carry save adder 1
               assign s11=(s1^s2^w)>>1;//S1'[i]
               assign s21=(s1&s2&w)>>1;//S2'[i]

               //carry save adder 2
               assign s12=(s11^s21^y)>>1;//S1[i+1]
               assign s22=(s11&s21&y)>>1;S2[i+1]

               //multiplexers 3 and 4
               assign s1=bypass?(s21>>1):s21;
               assign s2=bypass?(s22>>1):s22;

               //multiplexers 1 and 2
               if((A==0)&(q==0))
                  begin
                     assign w=4'h0;
                     assign y=4'h0;
                  end
               else if((A==0)&(q==1))
                  begin
                     assign w=N;
                     assign y=4'h0;
                  end
               else if((A==1)&(q==0))
                  begin
                     assign w=bd1;
                     assign y=bd2;
                  end
               else if((A==1)&(q==1))
                  begin
                     assign w=d1;
                     assign y=d2;
                  end
            end
      end
endmodule
```

Comment: Nothing can be said about your code simulation, unless you add your testbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `always begin ... end` is an infinite loop, time will not advance. Perhaps you meant `always @* begin ... end`
- Do not use *procedural continuous assignment*, aka `assign` statements inside `begin`-`end`. I already when over the reasons why and recommenced strategy to fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687699/1959732). In some case you need to drop the `assign` keyword, in other the line needs to be moved out of the procedural block.
- `while` loops are generally unsynthesizable. Use a `for` loop that can be statically unrolled.