# Problems assigning to LEDs in a case block

Tags: verilog

When I enter something like this:

```
always @* begin
    case(SW[17])
        1'b0: assign LEDG = SW[7:0];
        1'b1: assign LEDG = SW[15:8];
    endcase
end
```

where `LEDG` is set of [7:0] green LEDs, I get the error:

> Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at
> part2.v(20): object "LEDG" on left-hand side of assignment must have a
> variable data type

upon trying to compile.  However, when I put a similar assignment statement outside the case block, such as:

```
assign LEDG = SW[7:0];
```

it assigns just fine.  I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have declared LEDG as

```
wire [7:0] LEDG;
```

Change it to

```
reg [7:0] rLEDG;
wire [7:0] LEDG;
assign LEDG = rLEDG;
```

Your always block should now assign rLEDG.

Basically, always blocks cannot assign to wires, only regs. assign statements on the other hand, assign to wires not regs.

Answer (score 0):

Assign statements can't be used inside an always block. Remove 'assign' from the line and change your 'output [7:0] LEDG' array to 'output reg [7:0] LEDG' . A reg data type must be used inside always blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Using an assign like that you are most likely not doing what you expect. See [using-a-continous-assignment-in-a-verilog-procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687172/using-a-continous-assignment-in-a-verilog-procedure) for an explanation of what your currently doing.

To expand in DJZygotes answer, LEDG must be a `wire` for continuous `assign` or `reg` for assignment in an `always` or `initial` block.

```
wire [7:0] LEDG;
assign LEDG = SW[7:0];
```

Or:

```
reg [7:0] LEDG;
always @* begin
  case(SW[17])
    1'b0: LEDG = SW[7:0];
    1'b1: LEDG = SW[15:8];
  endcase
end
```