# how to force data in design instead of using testbench

Tags: verilog

hi guys i was wondering if there is a way to force bit in a design instead of using testbench? like verilog code for single port ram below how to force ram[address] into 1000 instead of using testbench?

```
module RAM(clk, rst, w, r, data, address, read, read_out);
parameter length = 4;
parameter depth = 8;
input clk, rst, r, w;
input [length-1:0] data, address;
output [length-1:0] read;
output reg[length-1:0] read_out;
reg[length-1:0] ram [depth-1:0];
assign read = ram[address];

always@(posedge clk) begin
if (!rst) begin
    if(w)
    ram[address] <= data;
    else if (r)
    read_out <= ram[address];
end
else begin
    if (w)
    ram[address] <= data;
end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **procedural continuous assignment** type of statements that have **precedence** over any procedural statements. These are `assign` statements inside `always` block.

Referring to example in SystemVerilog LRM [1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) Section 10.6,

> The *assign* procedural continuous assignment statement shall **override** all procedural assignments to a variable. The *deassign* procedural statement shall **end** a procedural continuous assignment to a variable.
>
> The value of the variable shall remain the **same** until the variable is assigned a new value through a procedural assignment or a procedural continuous assignment.

So, you can have a combinational `always` block to override the existing value:

```
module ram...
//...
//...
always@*
begin
//... Some logic 
assign ram[address] = whatever_data
// assign ram[address] = 'h1000;
//...
deassign ram[address];
//...
end

always@ (posedge clk, negedge reset)
begin
//...
//...
// No change here.
end

endmodule
```

A new continuous assignment process is created when the line is reached in the procedural block.

`assign` can be applied to all the types like `reg`, `integer` etc but not on **nets** (force must be used for nets).

Moreover, procedural continuous assignments are **synthesizable**.

However, they can easily be *misused* and hence they must be used **sparingly**. A better alternative is to find out some other driving logic.

For more information, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687172/using-a-continous-assignment-in-a-verilog-procedure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687172/using-a-continous-assignment-in-a-verilog-procedure) links. While, procedural continuous assignment can be found out at SystemVerilog LRM [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) section 10.6.

Comment: hi thx for replying when i try to use 


    always@(*) begin
     if(fi_ctrl)
     assign ram[address] = read_fi;
     else
     deassign ram[address];
    end

it shows error of Slice of unpacked array not allowed in procedural continuous assignment: ram