# Verilog code will simulate but won't synthesize.

Tags: verilog, fsm, synthesis, vivado

This is the code for my finite state machine

```
//
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//Moore Finite State Machine Lab 3
// 
// WORKING, needs Screen output

module moore(
    input BTNC,    //manual clk
    input SW0,     //clr
    input SW1,    
    input SW2,     
    input SW3,    
    input SW4,
    output reg [3:0] LED,    //z
    reg [2:0] y,Y
    );
    localparam S_00=3'b000, S_01=3'b001, S_02=3'b010,
               S_03=3'b011, S_04=3'b100;

//Define next state
    always @(y,SW0,SW1,SW2,SW3,SW4)
    begin
            case (y)
                S_00: if (SW1)      Y <= S_01;
                      else          Y <= S_00;
                S_01: if (SW1)      Y <= S_02;
                      else if (SW3) Y <= S_03;
                      else          Y <= S_01;
                S_02: if (SW1)      Y <= S_04;
                      else          Y <= S_02;
                S_03: if (SW2)      Y <= S_04;
                      else if (SW3) Y <= S_02;
                      else          Y <= S_03;
                S_04: if (SW2)      Y <= S_02;
                      else if (SW4) Y <= S_00;
                      else          Y <= S_04;
                      default:      Y <= 3'bxxx;
            endcase
        end 

    //Define state update
    always @(SW0, BTNC)
       begin
        if (!SW0) y <= S_00;
        else y <= Y;
       end  

    //Define output
    always @(y)
        if (y==S_00)
            begin 
            assign LED = 3'b000;
            end
        else if (y==S_01)
            begin
            assign LED = 3'b001;
            end
        else if (y==S_02) 
            begin
            assign LED = 3'b010;
            end
        else if (y==S_03)
            begin 
            assign LED = 3'b011;
            end
        else if (y==S_04)
            begin 
            assign LED = 3'b100;
            end
        else
            begin 
            assign LED = 3'b000;  //not used
            end
endmodule // lab3ht codename moore
```

and when trying to synthesize in vivado 2015.3 this is what it tells me

```
[Common 17-69] Command failed: Vivado Synthesis failed
[Synth 8-285] failed synthesizing module 'moore' ["C:/Users/C/Desktop/moore3h/moore3/moore3.srcs/sources_1/new/moore.v":6]
[Synth 8-27] procedural assign not supported ["C:/Users/C/Desktop/moore3h/moore3/moore3.srcs/sources_1/new/moore.v":51]
[Synth 8-567] referenced signal 'Y' should be on the sensitivity list ["C:/Users/C/Desktop/moore3h/moore3/moore3.srcs/sources_1/new/moore.v":41]
```

I know that delays cannot be synthesized, and I tried fixing this by getting rid
of always @(negedge BTNC) and using just the button press, but thats as far a my knowledge of verilog goes. I dont know why this cant be synthesized so i can later generate a bitstream and upload it to the basys3 board and use it there
Any insight is greatly appreciated, The code runs beautifully during the simulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the warnings. You have used `assign` statement in a procedural block making it a **procedural continuous assignment**.

```
[Synth 8-27] procedural assign not supported
```

These type of assignments are **synthesizable** by most of the tools, but they can easily be **misused** and hence **avoided** as far as possible. Your tool seems not supporting this type of statements. Hence, **remove** `assign` statement and use **simple blocking statement** in every `if..else if..else` condition.

```
// Remove assign
else if (y==S_04)
assign LED = 3'b100;
//...
// use simple blocking statements
else if (y==S_04)
LED = 3'b100;
```

Another warning related to `Y` is due to **incomplete sensitivity list** of `always @(SW0, BTNC)` block. You are using `else y=Y;` in this block. Henceforth `Y` must appear in sensitivity list.

```
[Synth 8-567] referenced signal 'Y' should be on the sensitivity list
```

For any **combinational** `always` block, the use of `always@(*)` or `always_comb` is **recommended**. This will **remove** any mistakes in providing **manual sensitivity**. You can convert the sensitivity of all the `always` blocks here (except for clocked `always` block) to `always@(*)`.

Also, your **next state logic** always block is a **combinational block**. You must use **blocking**(`=`) assignments in that block.

```
always @(*)
    begin
            case (y)
                S_00: if (SW1)      Y = S_01; // blocking assignment
                      else          Y = S_00; // blocking assignment
//...
```

Refer to [Procedural continuous assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687172/using-a-continous-assignment-in-a-verilog-procedure) question for more information. Also, [Verilog always block](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29553/how-are-verilog-always-statements-implemented-in-hardware) and [Blocking vs Non-Blocking statments usage question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog) links might be useful.